# Problems after replacing new battery on Macbook Pro 2017 A1706 (EMC3071)

Tags: laptop, keyboard, battery, macbook, touchpad

**Spec**

Macbook Pro 2017 A1706 (EMC3071)

Battery Model A1819

---

**Battery used in replacement**

EGOWAY A1706 A1819 Laptop Replacement Battery for MacBook Pro 13 inch Touch Bar Late 2016 Mid 2017 EMC 3071 3163 MLH12LL/A MPXV2LL/A MLVP2LL/A MNQF2LL/A MNQG2LL/A

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B096NLGXYH?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B096NLGXYH)

---

**Problems after replacing the new battery**

- Macbook runs very slow after login to the desktop
- keyboard isn't working
- trackpad isn't working

---

**Steps**

Before I started, I made sure that the macbook is in good working condition other than the battery that isn't holding the charge. Macbook was being worked on an anti-static mat. I was wearing glove and sitting in a chair that is on top of the rubber mat.

I made sure that the macbook is shutdown before i proceed. Then I carefully disassembled the macbook.

Things that was unhooked/unscrewed after back casing was removed

- motherboard holding screws
- trackpad connector to the mb
- keyboard connector to the mb
- ribbon cable from the battery controller board
- screws on the battery controller board

After the old battery was removed, I proceed to put in the new battery and put everything back in their place. Double check that everything is connected and internal screws are back in place. Then I put the back casing back on without putting the screws back in place before I proceed to turn the macbook on. Macbook wasn't turning on after pressing power button. I plugged in the power cable and try pressing the power button again. The macbook turned on after power cable is plugged in. Macbook booted up normal.

Things I noticed after the macbook booted up to the login screen

- Fan were running louder than usual
- Keyboard isn't working (not showing anything on the screen when trying to type the password at the login screen)
- Trackpad isn't working
- New battery is at 75% and charging

I then proceed to do SMC Reset. At the login screen, I press and hold Control + Option + Shift(on that same internal keyboard) and then hold the Power button. The macbook shutdown and restart itself right after I press the power button. To me, the SMC Reset is working. After macbook booted to the login screen, it is still having the same symptoms (keyboard isn't working, fan were running loud and trackpad isn't working).

Then I attempt to do PRAM Reset. I shutdown the macbook and wait about 1-2 minutes. I press power button and hold down Command + Option + P + R. Nothing happened during the boot. I did not see the apple logo flickering nor boot up sound going twice like it supposed to do when PRAM Reset is working.

So I plugged in the external keyboard and mouse to the macbook and login to the desktop. Everything was running very slow after that point.

**Troubleshoot steps**

- Tried reset smc again
- Tried reset pram again - not work
- Tried reset pram with external keyboard - not work
- Tried put old battery in - same result
- Looked in hardware list under USB - no internal keyboard nor trackpad were listed
- Tried only used power cable to turn on the macbook - same result
- Inspected and re-seated keyboard and trackpad connectors - nothing is out of ordinary.

Do I have a faulty keyboard and trackpad? Do I have a faulty new battery? What should I do now? Please help.

Comment: Is the battery Apple certified?  I think it needs to be.

Comment: I don't think it is. I didn't know that the battery has to be Apple certified.

Answer (score 0):

> Battery used in replacement.  EGOWAY A1706 A1819 Laptop Replacement
> Battery for MacBook Pro 13 inch Touch

Replacement batteries need to be certified (warranty approved if applicable) by the manufacturer.

True for Apple; true for Lenovo; and then as far as I know, true for HP and Dell.

So that is most likely why the computer had issues with the new third party battery.

Consider taking the machine to the Apple Store for a replacement battery and potentially some related service if necessary.